# sync SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to sync my sqlite database on android with the database on web server.

program should fill the local database on the tablet with the SELECT from the server, then user changes some data on his android-phone and sends new version to a server.
Are there any source code examples about such synchronization?

Will be very grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's better to connect using web servises. ksoap2 can help u if u stuck in the simillar situation [Ksoap2 home](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/)
example:[KSoap Android Web Service Tutorial With Sample Code](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html)

Answer (score 0):

SampleSyncAdapter sample app in the Developer guide.

This is exactly the situation for populating the Contacts Provider from a user's online contacts information.

Comment: that's better to connect using web servises. ksoap2 can help u if u stuck in the simillar situation [link](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/)
example:[link](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at the AndroidSyncApp tutorial located at:

http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/AndroidSyncApp

It covers how to use the OpenMobster Sync Framework by synchronizing objects from the Cloud with the Android device.

For slightly more advanced tutorials you can look at:
http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/PushMail

All the tutorials come with fully functional end-to-end apps and source code

Good Luck!!!